# How to render id and name, where i getting the API response

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, dropdown

## `

I'm trying to populate my select dropdown options with values that come from an API call as soon as the page loads. Currently, the options are only generated, how can i list options in select field. On page load, the options do not get filled and are empty. I've looked at other similar questions that suggest using the React-select package, but I'm looking for a way to do it with just react and I haven't had any luck finding a solution. Please advise on how I can achieve this or where I can get help. I've attached my code below. Kind regards.`

abc.js

> options &&
> options.map((newoptions) => (
>                                                 
>                                                  {newoptions.value}
>                                                 
>                                     ))
>                                  }
>                                   }

```
 `useEffect(() => {
                fetch("http://localhost:4000/add-batch")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then((res)=>{
                    const {data} = res;
                    setData(data);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    
                  })
            console.log("Data", data);
            const results = []
                  
            data.map((value) => {
                    results.push({
                    key: value.id,
                    value: value.batchName,
                    });
                });
                setOptions([
                     results
                ])
               
    }, []);`
```

database

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65b9dff4501239f11a2aedcb"
  },
  "programType": "Upskill Traningq",
  "batchName": "Upskill_03",
  "numberOfStudents": 20,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-31T05:51:48.858Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-01-31T05:51:48.858Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

how can i get the id value and batch name as dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple react component that lists the options you got from your api in a select field, hope its useful for you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/add-batch")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        const { data } = res;
        setData(data);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        // Do something if needed after fetching data
      });

    const results = data.map((value) => ({
      value: value.id,
      label: value.batchName,
    }));

    setOptions(results);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. but still, I didn't get the output. The options list shows no data. the function also runs continuously

Comment: @serohrt This will cause an infinite loop because you use a setter method ```setData(...)``` inside the ```useEffect``` and put ```data``` as dependency. So setter causes a rerender of updating data and since it is a dependency, the ```useEffect``` will be called again in an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

there are some errors in your code.
Basically you can't use async function inside `useEffect` like you did.

Instead of

```
useEffect(() => {
  const res = await fetch(URL)
  // stuff using res
}, [])
```

you need to wrap it into a function and call it inside the `useEffect`, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncFunc = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(URL)
    // stuff using res
  }
  // then call it
  asyncFunc();
}, [])
```

beyond that, if you don't need to store data into `data` local state for other reason than mapping the select option. you could store that into a local variable inside `then` function or after `await` and map the options using the local variable or directly using destructured data from the response (`const {data} = res`).

Instead, if you need to use the response in other places rather than mapping the select option, you should call the setter `setData(data)` as you did, but point to it in other `useEffect` which has `data` as a dependency, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const asyncFunc = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(URL)
    const data = res.json();
    setData(data);
  }
  // then call it
  asyncFunc();
}, [])


useEffect(() => {
  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    setOption(data.map(// mapping as you wish);
  } 
}, [data]);
```

Your code doesn't work properly because the setter of `useState` is not synchronous, instead they are scheduled. So when you call setOption from data (the `useState`, not the destructured one) you don't have the desired value inside data, you will have it at the end of the method when the component will be rendered.

I hope this will help you